# PHP check the form on the first page and then send it to another page if inputs were correct

Tags: php

I have a problem and I dont have a clue how to solve that, the thing is I have a form, then I check form for correct inputs and if user filled up required fields, it works, but then I need to send it to another page, and if inputs were wrong I need to stay on the same page. Will someone help me please?

Comment: we need to see the code.

Comment: Right; *you* have that.

Comment: *"Will someone help me please?"* - Help you "how"? IMHO, the question is too broad; do try something.

Comment: Can you please show me your code what you have tried till now

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $form = getFormFieldsFromPost($_POST);
    $isValid = validateForm($form);
    if ($isValid) {
        //todo
        redirectTo(SITE_PAGE_MAIN);
    } else echo 'Try again!';
}

function getFormFieldsFromPost($POST){
    //TODO: get fields from post as array
    $formFieldsArray = []; //TODO: ad form fields
    $fields = array_intersect_key($_POST, $formFieldsArray);
    return $fields;
}

function validateForm($form){
    //TODO: validate form fields
    foreach($form as $field){
        //TODO: validation
    }
}

function redirectTo($link){
    //TODO: change google to $link
    echo "<script> location.href='http://google.com'; </script>";
}

define('SITE_PAGE_MAIN', ' ');
```

Comment: how can you answer without seeing code? Also you have no explanation - how is OP meant to understand the issue and resolution?